# Amazon SNS CreatePlatformApplication directly in iOs

Tags: php, ios, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I would use the Amazon Web Service to send push notifications directly to a device.

Currently I have a php script that receives APNS ( iOS ) or GCM ( Android ) , but I have not yet found a way (no examples found on google) to derive the ARN Token by the AWS PHP SDK ( it would be nice if someone publish an example of this type ;) )

It's possible get the ARN directly from IOS or Android application? If yes, you can post me a sample code.
Do you also think is the best method? or is it better to use php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Mobile SDK for iOS](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/)